# Difference between Tax Amount and Base Tax Amount

Tags: tax

I am curious to what the difference is between Tax Amount and Base Tax Amount. I have dumped to the system.log the values of each and the Base Tax Amount is coming out a penny more than the Tax Amount.

Any insight on these two fields is greatly appreciated, and any ideas on why the two are different values is even more appreciated =]

Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Base tax amount (actually any field that starts with base_) is the value in the *default* store currency.

Tax amount (like other amount fields) is the value in the *selected* store currency.

If you have only one currency on your website then base_X and X should always have the same value. It's really strange that you get even 1 cent difference. Probably it has something to do with rounding prices.

Comment: an obvious question, what in this context is the difference between the _default_ store and the _selected_ store?  And for simple applications which is the set of fields you'd normally look at - the X field, or the base_X field?

Comment: "default" and "selected" do not refer to the store. They refer to the currency. "Default currency" and "selected currency".

Comment: OK, I see this in `core_config_data` as "default" currency (currency/options/default).  But what is "selected" currency?  And where in the process does one "select" currency, is this done by the customer or some function of the site? Oh and can it be changed by store?