# What is the difference between grand_total and base_grand_total of the order?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, totals

Can any one explain the difference between following attributes of the order?

`grand_total`
`base_grand_total`

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: More info on this here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2768/146

Comment: So simply any field starts with `base_` will have the `default store currency` while others which doesn't start with `base_` will have `current store currency` right?

Comment: @Marius : I have put as an answer whatever I absorbed from the link which you have provided. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

grand_total = current currency grand total

base_grand_total = store base currency grand total

Answer (score 4):

So basically the following will applied for the `base_` values and `non base_` values according to this link as provided by Marius.
[Difference between Tax Amount and Base Tax Amount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/difference-between-tax-amount-and-base-tax-amount/2768#2768)

```
Example : 

base_xxx -----------> default store currency

xxx ----------------> currency store currency
```