# Difference price in database

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, price, items

I am confusing in different price in magento.
what is difference between 
`base_price`
 `original_price`
 `base_original_price`
 `price_incl_tax`
 `base_price_incl_tax` in `sales_flat_order_item` table ?

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at this answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2768/33619 for explanation between base and original.
Here you can find description for BaseOriginal, Price, BasePrice : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156885/whats-the-differences-for-those-get-price-functions-in-mage-sales-model-quote-i